# Steering for gravity kart

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm planning to build a mini backpack gravity kart. Uphill by foot bringing kart in back, downhill driving offroad that kart.
So, it must be small, light, "flat" (similar to a skateboard).
I'm thinking about steer. My two choiches are:
- normal front wheel steering, driven by lateral lever instead of steering wheel
- fixed wheel, steering made by braking left or right brake

I prefer the second solution because of simplicity, the kart could be very minimal.
but I never seen kart like that, what are the cons of that steering system?

Comment: What about a three wheeler? See https://youtu.be/gQrI_PawqNA?t=249

Comment: Zero steering when the braked wheel leave the ground. Probably zero steering unless front and back wheels are braked. Have a look at Bobcat skid steer and ask yourself if this looks like a good steering system for a high-speed downhill kart.

Comment: Brake steering may not be as intuitive and may present some complications when trying to turn while slowing down. Zero degree turn tractors have a similar system, although it's steering by acceleration. 

If your inspiration is a skateboard, why not use that method of steering? Shifting your weight is enough to steer a skateboard, snowboard, skis, etc.